# Tables/Queries/Reports/VBA all gone after a compact and repair Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have been working on a database now for over a month. I did a compact and repair on it as I always do every now again but this time it has failed. When I re-open the database there is nothing, no tables, no queries.
I did however manage to retrieve the forms and the VBA code by importing them into a new blank database, so at least I haven't lost that. phew.

Is there anyway I can get the tables and queries back?
I know they are still there because the size of the database suggests the data remains.
Any 3rd party software to help if there is no Access tricks?

NB: I cannot use system restore and there is no recyle bin on my PC (work computer)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure they aren't just hidden? Also try and compact and repair operation. Backup the file first though and try it  with the database closed.

Comment: No they are not hidden unfortunately. How do you do a C&R while its closed?

Comment: I believe through the Tools menu. I don't have Access available right now.

Comment: If you want to try a compact and repair while the DB is closed, you can do it with a little VBScript--I have something set up at work. You can start by creating an Access application object in the script (`app = CreateObject("Access.Application"`). Then look up the Access Application object reference in MSDN. One of the methods listed should be a compact & repair method.